# spring-boot-starter-amqp dependency cause CglibAopProxy throws AmqpException while calling CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection()

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I'm trying to embed rabbitmq in a spring boot application. I followed various tutorials on the internet.
The spring boot version used is **V2.7.14**. I do have in my POM the `spring-boot-starter-amqp` dependency and in my propeties I also have the `spring.rabbitmq.*` defined.
The application starts correctly but all the producer-consumer logic does not work.
Looking at my startup logs I saw the following info:

```
o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy - Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.Connection org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection() throws org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException] because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK proxies instead!
```

I can't solve it. Still digging on the internet, a forum talks about **jmix** without going into too much detail.

Helps please!

Comment: And he problem is? That is an informational message and not causing issues. Panic about nothing? If it isn't working this isn't the reason.

Comment: The problem is that nothing is working. No connection is created, no queue is created. I don't see any such info in the logs. Also The @RabbitListener doesn't work. And the rabbitManager UI does not show any connection from a client.

Comment: Regardless the message you are focussing on is not the issue. Regarding your issue provide more information, is the package actually covered by Spring Boot, do you have all needed dependencies (rabbit mq etc).